# When app goes to Restricted App Standby Buckets

Tags: android, android-12, android-appstandby

As android-12 introduces a new **Restricted** standby mode. as per [android doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#restrictive-app-standby-bucket), it says the app goes to restricted mode based on app behavior + app usage

> The system considers your app's behavior, in addition to usage
> patterns, to decide whether to place your app in the restricted
> bucket. Your app is less likely to be placed in the restricted bucket
> if your app uses system resources more responsibly.

Q. What kind of app behavior puts an app into a restricted bucket? Any Example?